# Setup Nutch 1.3 and Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, nutch

I am a newbie to Nutch and Hadoop and trying to follow the tutorial here at http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchHadoopTutorial.

So I started with Nutch 1.3 release.

Even though Hadoop is included in Nutch, I did not see any of these .sh or .xml files referred in the tutorial under /nutch/search/conf after the build.

I was wondering if I have to setup hadoop first in the same directory structure or copy over hadoop config files before proceeding to Nutch setup.

Can anyone please put me in the right direction. I am pretty sure that I am lost :-(

Thanks very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well hadoop is not included anymore in Nutch since 1.3 ... I have complained in the mailing list. But the goal of Nutch group seem to have changed to a crawler component only. To make use of it you need to install hadoop [here is good tutorial](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster) & solr (for search).
Some people announced they are going to fix that but for Nutch1.4 only. Not sure where it will end up.

Comment: Thanks millebii. I have Nutch 1.3 and Hadoop running on Linux instance. I am trying to figure out if a Nutch crawl is using Hadoop frameworks to do the work. I will try to test again tonight and post my configuration here.

Comment: of course it does... its actually using it extensively. That's how you can store terabytes of pages and still get acceptable performance thx to mapreduce/clusters of Hadoop.